# Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized 32 - Could not authenticate you

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to get the data related to a specific hashtags from a specific location , but I am getting error.. I searched on the internet that it can be because of the *since* but I am not sure what to use instead of since in order not to get the error and my code work? any help or guidance appreciated!

```
import tweepy
import datetime

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = '-'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = '-'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = '-'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '-'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)


api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday= today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today, yesterday

tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="#Covid-19 since:" + str(yesterday)+ " until:" + str(today),tweet_mode='extended', lang='it').items()


place = 'London'
tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="place: " + place,tweet_mode='extended', lang='it').items()


output = []
for tweet in tweets_list:
    text = tweet._json["full_text"]
    print(text)
    favourite_count = tweet.favorite_count
    retweet_count = tweet.retweet_count
    created_at = tweet.created_at
    
    line = {'text' : text, 'favourite_count' : favourite_count, 'retweet_count' : retweet_count, 'created_at' : created_at}
    output.append(line)
```

The error:

```
Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you don't have the right twitter permissions.

You have different level of permissions that you can see [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions)

You have to login, change your permissions and regenerate your api key to get it working

Good luck

Comment: I have the key and token, i just didn't share it here , and about then services, can I check which one did specify? because I did it last month and can't remember

Comment: Thank you, that seemed was my problem and now it works :)